# How to change font to Calligra

Tags: fonts

I wish to have a result as in this [link](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligra/) for my entire paper (including title)

I followed the instruction to add the following code

```
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

but nothing happened... any suggestions? Thank you!

I use document class

```
\documentclass[english, 9pt,reqno]{amsart}
```

Comment: As noted in the example you link to, you need to issue `\calligra` to select (and subsequently use) the font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to issue `\calligra` in order to use the font, otherwise the reigning font will prevail.

However, under [`amsart`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsart) there are a number of issues of `\normalfont` for adjusting sectional and title headings - it's customary to "clear all font-related changes using `\normalfont` whenever you want to set "something special". So, you could change `\normalfont` to be `\calligra`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{calligra,lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\normalfont}{\calligra}
\AtBeginDocument{\normalfont}

\title{A title}
\author{An author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

You'll note though that a number of font-related warnings are issued with the above usage, as `\normalfont` (now `\calligra`) doesn't have an `\scshape` (used in `\section`s) nor `\bfseries` (used in `\title`).

Answer (score 1):

As @Werner stated, you must select the font you will use. The link you provided, the example, shows that.

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\usefont{T1}{fvm}{m}{n}}
\setkomafont{section}{\usefont{T1}{fvs}{b}{n}\Large}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\section*{Calligra}
\subsection*{\textbackslash calligra}
\normalfont\calligra %This is the command you need to add to your source file
The Calibra Font.
Just add the coman and you can use the Calibra Font
\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP uses a specific class that affects the use of `\calligra`. Also, it's called "Calligra" (from "Calligraphy"), not "Calibra". Finally, Why are you loading `babel`, `amsmath`, `array`, `slantsc`, `fontenc` and `inputenc` and setting unnecessary settings?